# Inner function with Kronecker products

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors

I am trying to calculate $\sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_2 + \sigma_2 \otimes \sigma_1$ as a inner product. My attempt

```
Inner[KroneckerProduct, {PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2]}, {PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[1]}, Plus]
```

does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: `Inner` strips all list levels from `{PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2]}`, not just the outer braces. Since `Inner` does not have a level option, I would say it is not suitable for the task.

Comment: You could do `Inner[KroneckerProduct, {a, b}, {b, a}, Plus] /. {a -> PauliMatrix[1],
   b -> PauliMatrix[2]
  }`.

Comment: ... also `Plus @@ MapThread[
  KroneckerProduct, {{PauliMatrix[1], 
    PauliMatrix[2]}, {PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[1]}}]`

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing [march's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140232/inner-function-with-kronecker-products#comment378780_140232).

You want to first construct an inner product, then insert Pauli matrices:

```
f[a_, b_] = Inner[KroneckerProduct, {a, b}, {b, a}, Plus]
f[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note the usage of `Set` (`=`) instead of the usual `SetDelayed` (`:=`).

Answer (score 1):

Some `Inactive[]` trickery gets the job done:

```
With[{p1 = Inactive[PauliMatrix][1], p2 = Inactive[PauliMatrix][2]}, 
     Inner[Inactive[KroneckerProduct], {p1, p2}, {p2, p1}, Plus] // Activate]
   {{0, 0, 0, -2 I}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {2 I, 0, 0, 0}}
```

(Use `Hold[]`/`ReleaseHold[]` in earlier versions.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Plus @@ MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {#, Reverse@#} &[PauliMatrix /@ {1, 2}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]